# Why are copies of whats in my array posting?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, dom-events

i want the value from my input to  render on my page when i click on my button to add text to my page. For some reason with the current code that i have, the new value from my input is displayed in addition to a copy of what was already there, so basically previous input values are showing more than once on the front end as opposed to a new item just being added to the list

heres a link to the codepen so you can see what happens https://codepen.io/matthew-angel/pen/jOmJLBW

```
// Log out "Button clicked!" when the user clicks the "SAVE INPUT" button
let myLeads = []
const button = document.querySelector("#input-btn")
const inputEl = document.querySelector("#input-el")
// let inputText = inputEl.value
const ulEl = document.querySelector("#ul-el")


button.addEventListener("click", addText)

function addText() {
console.log(inputEl.value)
myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
console.log(myLeads)
render()
}


function render(){
 
    for(let i = 0; i < myLeads.length; i++) {
         //   create element
        // set text content
        // append to ul
      let li =  document.createElement('li')
        li.innerText += myLeads[i]
        ulEl.appendChild(li)
       console.log(li)
       console.log(ulEl)
       console.log( li.textContent)  
    }
   
}
```

Comment: `li.innerText += myLeads[i]` adds the right-hand text to the left-hand text.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to describe, but every item I add in your CodePen simply appends to the list below.  The behavior looks entirely normal and expected to me.